# How do you get an attribute from a node in a nodelist?

Tags: xml, vb.net, nodes, xmlnode, nodelist

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in VB.

I have a ListBox populated by an XML file. 
I have managed to get a "Delete All" working, but I cannot manage to get a "Delete Single" working.  Not sure how to get the attribute values from a node in a nodelist. 
I need to match the title attribute for the Bookmark Elements with lstBookmarks.Text which holds the text of the listbox selected item.

Highlighted where the delete needs to take place( at least for my code).
I will gladly accept totally rewritten code as long as it is explained.

My XML looks like this

```
<Data>
    <Bookmark title="Page 1" link="Some File Path Here" />
    <Bookmark title="Page 2" link="Some Other File Path Here" />
</Data>
```

My Delete Looks like this

```
Private Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If lstBookmarks.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("There are no bookmarks to clear!")
        ElseIf lstBookmarks.SelectedValue.ToString() = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("There are no bookmarks to clear!")
        Else
            Dim xmlFile As String = filePath & "Resources\bookmark.xml"
            Dim XMLDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
            Dim nodes As XmlNodeList

            XMLDoc.Load(xmlFile)
            nodes = XMLDoc.SelectNodes("Data")

            Dim RootElement As XElement = XElement.Load(xmlFile)
            Dim DataElement As XmlElement = XMLDoc.DocumentElement
            Dim NewElement As XmlElement = XMLDoc.CreateElement("Bookmark")
            Dim FindElement = RootElement.<Bookmark>.Attributes("title")

            If DataElement.HasChildNodes Then
                For Each Attribute In FindElement
                    If Attribute = lstBookmarks.Text Then
                        '************************************************
                        'Match found, delete node or XML Element here
                        '************************************************
                    Else
                        'No Match in XML, no need to delete
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the element using the `XmlDocument` class, you can do so easily with XPath, like this:

```
Dim xPath As String = String.Format("/Data/Bookmark[@title='{0}']", lstBookmarks.Text)
Dim theNode As XmlNode = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode(xPath)
```

Or, you can find it using the `XDocument` or `XElement` class using LINQ to XML like this:

```
Dim theElement As XElement = RootElement.<Bookmark>.First(Function(x) x.@title = lstBookmarks.Text)
```

Or:

```
Dim theElement As XElement = (From i As XElement 
                              In RootElement.<Bookmark> 
                              Where i.@title = lstBookmarks.Text 
                              Select i).First()
```

You can use XPath to find nodes in `XDocument` / `XElement` objects as well.

Comment: Thank you much.  I was able to use your first example to do exactly what I needed. I was then able to loop through the nodelist and then just do node.RemoveChild(theNode).